# Build ranges by index of columns in Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to connect cells that range from column(index i) to column(index j).
The column indices are written in a Excelsheet `"Tabelle1"` in the columns A and B:

i... starting index  (e.g. 4 = D, 6 = F...)
j... end index

[image]

To do this, I first would try to build ranges that represent the cells, which need to be connected (e.g.: N10:AD10).

In the case of rows within a column, the solution was easy:

```vb
Sub testlaufZP()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim combo As Range

For i = 1 To 100

    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
    
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")

        Set rng1 = .Range("E" + Cells(i, 1).Text)
        Set rng2 = .Range("E" + Cells(i, 2).Text)
        Set combo = .Range(rng1.Address & ":" & rng2.Address)
    
        Cells(i, 4) = combo.Address
    
        End With

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

But how do I build ranges across columns instead?

I saw some iteration approaches over the alphabet by the function `toCharArray()` but it´s quite a uncomfortable approach due to my data table is reaching from columns G:TD

Later I want to use these ranges to merge these cells.

Comment: `.Cells(rowNum,colNum)` lets you loop `for colNum = lbound to ubound`.

Comment: Okay, so i would need a different way to merge the cells afterwards instead of e.g.: 
Sub MergeCells()
    Range("D5:D12").Merge
End Sub

Comment: In your merge-example comment, you have a fixed range, so that wouldn't change.  Depending if you want to merge a dynamic row, that may allow you to work with what you have, though with `.cells()`, you would write `.Range(.Cells(5,4),.Cells(12,4))`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i will implement that and give an update.

Comment: Please note the use of dot notation needing to be carried through.  `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` would need to be referenced for each `range`/`cells` reference to qualify them, so be mindful when writing, as you currently use unqualified ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Cyril, your approach solved the problem. Implemented it (defining ranges, merging) this way inside the bigger makro:

```
Dim rng1 As range
Dim val1 As Long
Dim val2 As Long
Dim deviation As Long

deviation = 40

For i = (deviation + 5) To 1000

    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Zeittafel")
                        
        val1 = Cells(i, 2).Value
        val2 = Cells(i, 3).Value
        
        Set rng1 = .range(.Cells(i - deviation, val1), .Cells(i - deviation, val2))
        
        Cells(i, 4) = rng1.Address
        
        range(rng1.Address).merge
        range(rng1.Address).Select
        
        'HIER WIRD DER TEXT AUS DER 2ten SPALTE ZUGEWIESEN
        
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Cells(i - deviation, 2).Value
        
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
        
    End With
    End If
    
Next
```